# How do I align tablenotes in a threeparttable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, threeparttable, tablenotes

Edit: Now I realize there is a issue with very long notes, specially because I am working with A5 paper.
Using Mica's solution:

[image: Long note]

Having the `tablenotes` `flushleft` however works just fine.

Two questions in one:

- How do I align the `tablenotes` to start at the left of the table and figure? (The `flushleft` option of `threeparttable` does affect the whole threeparttable and creates inconsistency)
- Why my code displays this difference in the `tablenotes`, when comparing figure and table?

[image: tablenotes misalignment]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conv. auto. dos acentos)
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[range-phrase={\,a\,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    group-digits=true,
    group-four-digits=true,
    group-separator={\,},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    justification=justified,
    %labelsep=quad,
    labelsep=endash, %% ABNT q manda
    position=above,
    skip=\onelineskip,
    width=0.95\linewidth,
}
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{threeparttable}{\centering}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}        
\begin{figure}[]
    \captionof{figure}{Pressão}
    \label{fig:pvapor2}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[grid=both,trim axis left, trim axis right,
        xlabel={Something else}, ylabel={Something},
        xmin= 1150,
        xmax=1550,
        ymin=-0.02
        ]
        \addplot+[ultra thick] coordinates { 
            (1300-273,101325*4.278*10^-11)
            (1400-273,101325*8.133*10^-10)
            (1500-273,101325*1.040*10^-8)
            (1600-273,101325*9.636*10^-8)
            (1687-273,101325*5.377*10^-7)
            (1700-273,101325*6.662*10^-7)
            (1800-273,101325*3.117*10^-6)
            (1900-273,101325*1.238*10^-5)
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item Fonte: Autor.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \captionof{table}{Planejamento}
    \label{tab:planejamentoexperimental}
    \begin{threeparttable}[t]
        \begin{tabular}{@{}SSSS @{}}
            \toprule
            \text{Ordem} & \text{Ensaio} & \text{Fator A} & \text{Fator B} \\
            \midrule
            12 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
            5 & 2 & -1.41421 & 0\\
            2 & 3 & 1 & -1\\
            11 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
            13 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
            10 & 6 & 0 & 0\\
            8 & 7 & 0 & 1.41421\\
            1 & 8 & -1 & -1\\
            9 & 9 & 0 & 0\\
            7 & 10 & 0 & -1.41421\\
            3 & 11 & -1 & 1\\
            4 & 12 & 1 & 1\\
            6 & 13 & 1.414214 & 0\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item Fonte: Autor.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow `threeparttable` reads the last tables size, this does not work for your Ti*k*Z picture, which explains the difference in behaviour?

Comment: I remember having head some luck with `\renewcommand\TPTminimum{\linewidth}` but dont know how exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following example, I have used the `flushleft` option to the individual `tablenotes` environments. I have also embedded the `tikzpicture` in a `tabular` environment to overcome the alignment issue there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conv. auto. dos acentos)
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[range-phrase={\,a\,}]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    group-digits=true,
    group-four-digits=true,
    group-separator={\,},
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    justification=justified,
    %labelsep=quad,
    labelsep=endash, %% ABNT q manda
    position=above,
    skip=\onelineskip,
    width=0.95\linewidth,
}
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\centering}
\setfloatadjustment{threeparttable}{\centering}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}        
\begin{figure}[]
    \caption{Pressão}
    \label{fig:pvapor2}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[grid=both,trim axis left, trim axis right,
        xlabel={Something else}, ylabel={Something},
        xmin= 1150,
        xmax=1550,
        ymin=-0.02
        ]
        \addplot+[ultra thick] coordinates { 
            (1300-273,101325*4.278*10^-11)
            (1400-273,101325*8.133*10^-10)
            (1500-273,101325*1.040*10^-8)
            (1600-273,101325*9.636*10^-8)
            (1687-273,101325*5.377*10^-7)
            (1700-273,101325*6.662*10^-7)
            (1800-273,101325*3.117*10^-6)
            (1900-273,101325*1.238*10^-5)
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
            \item Fonte: Autor.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Planejamento}
    \label{tab:planejamentoexperimental}
    \begin{threeparttable}[t]
        \begin{tabular}{@{}SSSS @{}}
            \toprule
            \text{Ordem} & \text{Ensaio} & \text{Fator A} & \text{Fator B} \\
            \midrule
            12 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
            5 & 2 & -1.41421 & 0\\
            2 & 3 & 1 & -1\\
            11 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
            13 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
            10 & 6 & 0 & 0\\
            8 & 7 & 0 & 1.41421\\
            1 & 8 & -1 & -1\\
            9 & 9 & 0 & 0\\
            7 & 10 & 0 & -1.41421\\
            3 & 11 & -1 & 1\\
            4 & 12 & 1 & 1\\
            6 & 13 & 1.414214 & 0\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
            \item Fonte: Autor.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that you're not using any `\tnote` directives, employing the `threeparttable` machinery and a `tablenotes` environment seems inappropriate or, at the least, like massive overkill. The simplest solution for your formatting objective would appear to consist of place the "Fonte" ("source", right?) line *into the body* of the `tabular` environment. In the code below, that's done by writing

```
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Fonte: Autor.}
```

While you're making ajdustments, you should be a bit more deliberate in the way you use the `S` column type, especially in view of the fact that the `SSSS` one-size-fits-all approach is ill advised.

The same argument holds for the treatment of the material in the `figure` environment: There's no need for the `threeparttable` environment machinery. Just place the `tikzpicture` environment in a single-column `tabular` environment, with column type `@{}l@{}`, and let the second row consist of

```
\footnotesize Fonte: Autor. % second "row"
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}     % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase={\,a\,},
         group-digits=true,
         group-four-digits=true,
         group-separator={\,},
         output-decimal-marker={,}
         }
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=justified,
              %labelsep=quad,
              labelsep=endash, %% ABNT q manda
              position=above,
              skip=1ex,
              %width=0.95\linewidth,
              }
\setfloatadjustment{table}{\centering}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}        
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example

\begin{table}
    \caption{Planejamento}
    \label{tab:planejamentoexperimental}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{S[table-format=2.0]}
                        *{2}{S[table-format=-1.5]} @{}}
    \toprule
    {Ordem} & {Ensaio} & {Fator A} & {Fator B} \\
    \midrule
    12 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    5 & 2 & -1.41421 & 0\\
    2 & 3 & 1 & -1\\
    11 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
    13 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
    10 & 6 & 0 & 0\\
    8 & 7 & 0 & 1.41421\\
    1 & 8 & -1 & -1\\
    9 & 9 & 0 & 0\\
    7 & 10 & 0 & -1.41421\\
    3 & 11 & -1 & 1\\
    4 & 12 & 1 & 1\\
    6 & 13 & 1.414214 & 0\\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\footnotesize Fonte: Autor.}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Pressão}
    \label{fig:pvapor2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[grid=both,trim axis left, trim axis right,
        xlabel={Something else}, ylabel={Something},
        xmin= 1150,
        xmax=1550,
        ymin=-0.02
        ]
        \addplot+[ultra thick] coordinates { 
            (1300-273,101325*4.278*10^-11)
            (1400-273,101325*8.133*10^-10)
            (1500-273,101325*1.040*10^-8)
            (1600-273,101325*9.636*10^-8)
            (1687-273,101325*5.377*10^-7)
            (1700-273,101325*6.662*10^-7)
            (1800-273,101325*3.117*10^-6)
            (1900-273,101325*1.238*10^-5)
        };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\ % end of first "row"
    \footnotesize Fonte: Autor. % second "row"
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I like your solution. I don't quiet understand your comment about t `S` usage, could you elaborate more? I totally ignore the difference in format `1.5` and `2` :(
Also, lets say in the future I need to add a table with `tnote`s, thus using `threeparttable`, wouldn't it create a inconsistency in my thesis?

Comment: @G.Bay - My apologies for not being clear. If no `table-format` option is given, the `S` column type assumes that the number of digits before and after the (explicit or implicit) decimal marker is the same. If you look closely at the screenshot that goes with your query, you'll notice that the numbers in the first two column looks *left-shifted*, because the numbers have no decimal components. Conversely, the numbers in the final two columns looks like they've been right-shifted, as there is only 1 digit to the left of the decimal marker but up to 5 digits to the right of the decimal marker.

Comment: @G.Bay - I don't quite follow your concern about a possible inconsistent look across `table` environments that do or do not contain `tablenotes` components. Just be sure to load the `threeparttable` environment with the option `flushleft`.

Comment: thank you a lot! The difference in the looks is so tiny that I think it's not worth editing my question. But it does look difference: https://imgur.com/aIPvLwd

Comment: @G.Bay - Indeed: In your code, since there are no `\tnote` directives, the argument of `\item` in the `tablenotes` environment has to be left empty. Because LaTeX is very much expecting an argument, it treats the space after `\item` in `\item Fonte: Autor.` as the argument of `\item`. That's why, in your code, the `Fonte: Autor.` ends up not being typeset fully flushleft.

Comment: And I suppose there is no way to fix this other then keeping the `tablenote` just for... `tnote`s as the name suggest ?

Comment: @G.Bay - I'm afraid I've lost the point of this thread. I continue to believe that if you load the `threeparttable` package with the option `flushleft`, you'll get good results if there's a point to employing a `tablenotes` environment, *viz.*, when there are some `\tnote` directives in the body of the tabular environment which require some corresponding non-trivial `\item` directives in the `tablenotes` environment. OTOH, if there are no `\tnote` directives to begin with, I simply don't understand why anyone would want to use a `tablenotes` environment and fill it with trivial `\item`s.